# Cannot set the color scheme in VIM

Tags: linux, vim

I am trying to set the color scheme [Wombat](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1778) in VIM. I followed the instructions as:

1. Downloaded the wombat.vim file to the location `~/.vim/colors/ directory`
2. Opened the VIM editor and set the color scheme by `:colorscheme wombat`

However, the editor remains unchanged after running the command. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Looks like the problems with the terminal and colors. Some color schemes are designed for `gvim` or terminals that support more than `256` colors (are they exist?), so they won't work in all other terminals. There are color schemes with `256` suffix, like `Wombat256` or `desert256` that should fix this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try some radically different colorscheme first, like `murphy`, then switch back to wombat. If nothing changes, then vim probably can't read your `wombat.vim`, check permissions on the file and on the colors dir to be sure.

Otherwise if you're seeing colors, but missing gray background, it most likely means that your terminal does not support 256 colors as @maverik mentioned. Try setting you terminal emulation to `xterm-256color` (if your OS supports it) and try again.

Answer (score 6):

Try `set t_Co=256` in your .vimrc. This could be a problem with your terminal not supporting 256 colors.